# Como puedo mandar el id junto con un evento en Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-directivas

Tengo el siguiente método definido:

```
elclick(id:string) {
    console.log('El id es: ' + id);
}
```

Y mi html es el siguiente:

```
<a id="0" (click)="elclick(this.id);">Button</a>
```

¿Cual es la manera en la que se hace esto?

Comment: Eso es en javascript, si funciona, el problema es que yo lo requiero en typescript, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por los tags que colocaste das a entender que usas angular para este caso.

Podrías usar lo siguiente:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <button (click)="onClick($event)" id="test">Click</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  onClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.srcElement.attributes.id);
    var idAttr = event.srcElement.attributes.id;
    var value = idAttr.nodeValue;
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

Comparando con la implementación de javascript cambia el hecho de que no se envía el `this` sino que se envía directamente el evento click `event`; este evento cuenta con toda la información que necesitas, en este caso el elemento Source `srcElement` que sería tu botón y sus respectivos atributos `attributes`, como el id `event.srcElement.attributes.id`